# Techniques to develop software and hardware of a SoC in parallel

Tags: digital-logic, soc, rtl

Hardware development takes a lot of time to develop. If a company is building a System-on-chip (SoC), the RTL model of the SoC is only available after the RTL integration is complete. This requires that the RTL design of each component and bus of the SoC to be complete in order to start software development (system software like device drivers and compilers) of the SoC.

RTL Design takes a lot of time to complete, software development for the SoC takes a lot of time too. If the company begins software development after RTL Design is ready, it would take a lot of time for the company to ship the product.

Are there techniques for developing software and RTL in parallel?

Comment: I disagree with your assumption that software development waits until the RTL design is complete. In my experience, these two proceed in parallel, with periodic regression testing as modifications occur.

Comment: You said "This requires that the RTL design of each component and bus of the SoC to be complete in order to start software development". I disagree with this assertion. Now that you mention it, you are contradicting yourself by later saying that this is not necessary.

Comment: RTL is not equivalent to System C. Using RTL **does not** imply that System C must be used. RTL is a **style** of simulation model, and it can be created in many languages using many tools. How do you think this has been done for the last 50 years?

Comment: No, you asked "without using virtual platforms / **virtual prototyping tools like SystemC & TLM 2.0**". If you want to change the question, I want your definition of "virtual platform" first. And I say again that people have been doing these designs for five decades. Are you suggesting that these "virtual platforms" have existed since the 1970s, or do you assert that they did not exist at that time?

Comment: Please answer the last question in my previous comment, specifically with respect to the term "virtual platforms".

Comment: Is any "model" of a processor a "virtual platform" for that processor? Are the two terms, "model" and "virtual platform", interchangeable or is there some difference between the two? Can we say that "virtual platforms" existed long before System C?

Comment: How do you suppose that software was written for the very first "processor", if there was no predecessor on which to create a "virtual platform"? There had to be a "first one", right, that was created without a simulation model?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson yes, you are right. Another user has written an answer mentioning how RTL and software can be developed in parallel without using virtual platforms. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/574589/238188

Comment: https://www.design-reuse.com/news_img/20090413_1.gif

Comment: I have worked with several major designs where S/W H/W started concurrently. Neither started until a good spec with measurable parameters on the interface was complete 1st pass. This forces the design of test to be included in spec and concurrent with product development with target tools known for DVT.  That includes self-test, ICT and FT.  Now there is a Co-Verification Debugger to merge RTL , C and H/W DVT

Comment: in the mid-80's we had a 4x4 bit slice to quad dual port 4 channel SCSI with 64k of hand coded self test with loop-back on everything.  OK not SoC. PCB looked like an areal photo of NYC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are also companies that develop Software (SW) and RTL in parallel **and in cooperation between SW and RTL developers**. Such development is typically done in small iterations where each iteration also includes integration of the functionality developed so far. Integration can be done on an FPGA regardless if that is the target technology or not. Let's say that you're developing an accelerator in the RTL accessed by SW. A typical first step would be to focus on the interface. Registers and drivers. A driver typically don't care about the data received from the accelerator so the first step can focus on the control signals. For example, the RTL can start by implementing a command register and an interrupt register. Whenever the "accelerator" is commanded to do something it can immediately respond with a done interrupt without performing any real work. Still, this first iteration will get the bus up and running and some basics use cases can be verified. Once that is done you take the next small step that pushes the RTL and SW forward. Once the two parts are complete they have already been integrated and largely verified which removes much of the downstream project risks of finding major mistakes that require large redesigns.

Comment: This is a good point. But there would be some disadvantages with not using the virtual platform approach: 1. Virtual platform enables early SoC performance and functional verification 2. Virtual platform can be reused as the reference model during RTL Verification. 3. Virtual platform can be used by software teams as a platform to run their code on. They don't need FPGA expertise when they use virtual platforms.

Comment: 4. For large SoCs, architects develop the virtual platform which is the executable specification used by both hardware and software teams

Comment: Yes, high-level models are good for early design space exploration. Note that these models are approximations of the end system that also have bugs as any other engineering artifact. The sooner they are put to the test the better. Just like iterative and parallel  development of RTL and SW avoids late surprises, iterative development of  the architecture serves the same purpose. As soon as some architectural concept has been decided upon it can be reviewed and handed to RTL/SW implementation to see if it works out as intended

Answer (score 1):

- In Electronic System-Level Design, the first step is to write  *high-level behavioural* models of hardware and simulate these models to analyse system performance.
- Software can run on these models. Thus, these behavioural models enable early software development, even before the RTL Design has begun. They can be written quickly, since micro-architectural details are not developed at this stage. They also simulate faster, since they are less timing-accurate than an RTL Model.
- The high-level models are usually written in C/C++ and are called **C models**. Depending on the application for which the model is written, they can be either loosely-timed or approximately-timed.
- Approximately-timed models are used for performance modeling and verification, while loosely-timed models are used for software development. An example for a loosely-timed model is the Instruction Set Simulator of a processor.
- SystemC is an IEEE standard C++ library that is used to enable a standard methodology for model development, called Transaction Level Methodology (Standardised as TLM 2.0). SystemC is a system-level design language and supports multiple levels of abstractions including RTL. Vendors provide C models of their processors wrapped in a SystemC module, to enable easy interfacing to testbenches and other EDA tools.
- ARM provides the [Fast Models](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/simulation-models/fast-models) for early software development.
- For almost all processors the QEMU models which are freely available can be used for software development.
- [Open Virtual Platforms](https://www.ovpworld.org/) by Imperas are freely open-source processor models to use with their proprietary simulator, OVPsim.
- The high-level model can be reused as the reference model during simulation and emulation. See: [hardware software co-simulation in HDL simulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/525202/238188)
- An open-source virtual platform of a Deep Learning Accelerator designed by NVIDIA, modeled using SystemC and contains an Arm processor modeled using QEMU: http://nvdla.org/vp.html

**References and Resources:**

- [IEEE 1666-2011 - IEEE Standard for Standard SystemC Language Reference Manual](https://standards.ieee.org/standard/1666-2011.html)
- [Official SystemC Community website](https://www.accellera.org/community/systemc/)
- [The power of virtual prototyping: From SoC design to software development - White Paper by ARM](https://armkeil.blob.core.windows.net/developer/Files/pdf/white-paper/virtual-prototyping-soc-design.pdf)
- [Better Software. Faster! Best Practices in Virtual Prototyping -  Ebook by Synopsys](https://www.synopsys.com/verification/virtual-prototyping/vp-book/download-vp-book.html)
- [SystemC Modeling Library by Synopsys](https://www.synopsys.com/cgi-bin/slcw/kits/reg.cgi)

Comment: Interesting discussion. +1. I'll need to think about it more. But it seems good enough just skimming over it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you cite authoritative sources to show that this is more than just your **opinion**? Perhaps for processors that are not ARM?

Comment: I said nothing about x86, why did you? But you didn't answer my question. You have made an assertion that "this is how everyone does it" with next to nothing for evidence. Can you back this up?

Comment: You have not defined a clear distinction between "software models" and "RTL". You have talked about various commercial products but not cited any authoritative sources saying that the method you describe is in fact "**widely used**" "**When a custom processor is developed**". You make implications and assertions that are not supported by references or citations. The fact that a tool exists and has an IEEE standard does not mean that it is actually used, or used more than another tool that has an IEEE standard. This answer is your **opinion**, nothing more.

Comment: All - Please keep things calm & civil and remember the [Code of Conduct](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/conduct). *Polite* technical disagreement is allowed. However, don't post anything that could *feel* personal, even when applied to content and not the person. One or more comments have already been deleted because of this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The companies advertising for System C experience may be using the tools for a **different purpose** than you suggest, such as providing models for University educational users. You have shown that such tools **can** be used, but you haven't shown, for example, that they "have become popular and are widely used". In my professional experience, a wide variety of tools are used by large companies and many of these tools are proprietary in nature...so they won't talk about them. My difficulty is that you are extrapolating too much from limited information.

Comment: -1: I work for the company that gave the presentation to Synopsys that inspired SystemC (as in: our original codebase still forms the basis of SystemC). We're probably the *world*'s foremost experts (together with Synopsys) on using the library in industry. No one here would support the notion that SystemC is widely used beyond a few companies that use it extensively.